# cloud foundry setup

Tags: cloud-foundry

I meet a question in setup multi-node cloud foundry(4 nodes).
  The first

question is:I Install Rest of the Components ,when I execute ~/dev_setup$ bin/vcap_dev_setup -c deployments/sample/multihost_mysql/rest.yml ,there are errors occurs:

```
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/multiverse Sources [2,354B]                                                                                          
Fetched 2,276kB in 38s (58.6kB/s)                                                                                                                                     
Reading package lists... Done
Installing wget...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
wget is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 129 not upgraded.
Checking web connectivity.
Giving up. Cannot connect to the web. Check your proxy settings if you are behind a proxy.
  In my network we don't use http proxy.I check vcap_dev_setup  shell,find error occurs at 113 line. I notes it ,is that ok?
  After this ,I run it again,but some other errors occur:
  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 129 not upgraded.

Launching chef...
Installing deployment rest, cloudfoundry home dir is /home/user/cloudfoundry
Input Error: Please provide valid install jobs, following jobs are not recognized
#<Set: {"mongodb", "redis"}>
```

why? Please help me,thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you behind a firewall or proxy of some sort?

Comment: we have firewall, but have no proxy. These have no limited for any website or port.

Comment: Sorry，I see your note today.I can use  curl api.cloudfoundry.com/info, it returns a jason String，but it also occurs "Installing deployment rest, cloudfoundry home dir is /home/user/cloudfoundry".Why? help me

Comment: There must be a network issue of some sort, this is why vcap_dev_setup fails at this point. Take a look at line 114 of https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap/blob/master/dev_setup/bin/vcap_dev_setup